# Lookup the second largest value in a specific set of column values (Without creating a new column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that looks something like this

```
Employee Date
Sean     21-07-2012
Peter    19-08-2012
Tammy    19-08-2012
Sean     14-07-2012
Sean     07-07-2012
Mickey   09-07-2012
Mickey   24-07-2012
Jean     27-07-2012
Jean     13-07-2012
Jean     07-07-2012
Victor   17-08-2012
Victor   10-08-2012
```

Let's say I want to get the second largest date for Jean. I found the following tutorial:
http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/

and I tried to use the top method this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A='Jean')*LARGE(B:B,2))
```

I am getting a large number which doesn't make sense. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Nice try with combining the concepts, but there are a few things wrong with this. Essentially what your formula is doing is looking up the second largest date overall, and multiplying it by itself for each time there's a 'jean' in column A. See my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following formula instead:

```
=LARGE(IF(A:A="Jean",B:B),2)
```

(Note this is an array formula, so you need to push <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> after typing it in)

What this does is it takes column A, and if it contains "Jean" then it gives the corresponding date from column B into the `Large` formula. This way the `Large` formula is only working with the dates that meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the person who entered the `<kbd>` tags to my answer. I was wondering how to do that!

Comment: Nice - but be aware that using full column references is much less efficient in array formulas so i'd suggest restricting to the specified range like this `=LARGE(IF(A2:A13="Jean",B2:B13),2)` (the difference is 90 vs 0.003 ms on my setup). If you want a dynamic range you can set up a table and use structured references.